# Why am I receiving no IRestResponse to a RestRequest?

Tags: c#, excel, restsharp

I’m really new to this particular area of programming (so feel free to really dumb things down for me).

Essentially, I am to pull in an excel file containing product information, loop through it and reformat the data, then send that data out to SureDone’s API.

I'm reading in the data fine so formatting it isn't an issue, however, in terms of the API stuff, I’m obviously missing something because I’m not getting anything returned in my txtResponse textbox.

I might be missing an overall concept, I’m not sure exactly what response I’m supposed to be receiving. I’ve pretty much started from scratch with very little knowledge of how all of this works and could really use any guidance at all.

Here’s my code:

```
private void btnLoad_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string PathConn = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=" + txtChooseFile.Text + ";Extended Properties=\"Excel 8.0;HDR=Yes;\";";
    OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection(PathConn);

    OleDbDataAdapter da = new OleDbDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM [" + txtLoad.Text + "$]", conn);
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();

    da.Fill(dt);

    dataGridView.DataSource = dt;

    String payload = "";
    int i = 1;

    foreach(DataRow row in dt.Rows)
    {
        //REST request -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        var client = new RestClient("https://www.api.suredone.com/v1/editor/items/add");
        var request = new RestRequest(Method.POST);
        request.AddHeader("x-auth-token", "tokenString");
        request.AddHeader("x-auth-user", "username");
        request.AddHeader("content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
        //--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

        Hashtable postData = new Hashtable();

        postData["action"] = row["action"].ToString();
        postData["sku"] = row["sku"].ToString();
        postData["stock"] = row["stock"].ToString();
        postData["price"] = row["price"].ToString();
        postData["msrp"] = row["msrp"].ToString();
        postData["title"] = row["title"].ToString();
        postData["longDescription"] = row["longdescription"].ToString();
        postData["condition"] = row["condition"].ToString();
        postData["brand"] = row["brand"].ToString();
        postData["notes"] = row["notes"].ToString();

        String formBoundary = "undefined";

        foreach (DictionaryEntry entry in postData)
        {    
            payload += "--" + formBoundary + "\r\n" + "Content-Disposition: form-data; name=" + entry.Key.ToString() + "\r\n\r\n" + entry.Value.ToString() + "\r\n\r\n";   
        }

        i++;

        //REST response -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        request.AddParameter("application/x-www-form-urlencoded", payload, ParameterType.RequestBody);
        IRestResponse response = client.Execute(request);
        txtResponse.Text = response.Content;
        //---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    }

    txtProducts.Text = payload;   
}
```

Comment: The API request might be failed. Try to check the value of `response.ResponseStatus`, `response.StatusCode`, and `response.ErrorMessage`.

Comment: According to [SureDone API Documentation](https://www.suredone.com/guides/api/#items-items-post-3), `/editor/items/add` endpoint requires these four parameters: `identifier`, `guid`, `price`, and `title`. You didn't include `identifier` and `guid` parameter in your code, so that might be the reason why you didn't get anything in `response.Content`.